# What is HTTP Content type "application/save-as"?

Tags: http, http-headers

In CMSimple `cms.php` file there is a function called "download", with this line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/save-as');
```

I know that the `header` function allows to set the header of the current request, but I have never heard of `application/save-as` content type.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's no such [MIME type registered](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/).

It's probably being used as a hack to trigger download, since (in theory) no application will have registered itself as being able to open it.

Comment: Furthermore, it's unnecessary to abuse the content-type header field for that. Use content-disposition instead.